# Condense Repeated Excel Formula Cell References into one Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to condense Excel Formula references into one reference while keeping the formula contained to one cell?

For reference the formula I am using is

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(G4,LEN(G4)-
 MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},G4&"0123456789"))+1),"-","."))
```

Which References G4 multiple times, I would like someway to make it so I or another user only has to change G4 in one place should the change be required.

Perhaps something like this (Not real excel formula:)

```
=MULTIPLEX(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(#1,LEN(#1)-
 MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},#1&"0123456789"))+1),"-",".")),#1,G4)
```

So that the #1 does not need to be changed and the G4 being changed once updates the whole formula.

I was trying to avoid VBA so that it is a user friendly formula, I will not be the only one using it.

Side note an implementation of my theoretical multiplex formula would allow for multiple references to be made. Syntax would be like `MULTIPLEX([formula],[ref1],[cell1],[ref2],[cell2],...)`

Side Side note the Formula is meant to extract the number from an item identifier for sorting purposes. ABC1234-1 becomes 1234.1 so we can sort by number ascending.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numeric part is at most 9 characters (including the "-") then you can use this formula to extract, which only references G4 once

`=LOOKUP(10^10,SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(G4,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}),"-",".")+0)`

Comment: Though this solves my problem (and I will certainly switch to this formula) I wouldn't say it answers the question in cases where the same thing would be helpful for much larger formulas. I imagine the solution will probably involve VBA which also isn't ideal but I suppose everything has limitations. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I'm late (by 6 years) but for the other people coming in, it's quite complicated.

```
=Indirect(Substitute(Address(1,Cell("col")-1;4);"1";"")&Cell("row")-1)
```

Look up for Indirect, Substitute, Address, Cell on your own, I will just explain how to use this formula.

So there's -1, twice up there. The first one is for column, second one is row. Minus (-) is for Return the result of Column/Row before it and for after, Plus (+).

Say, you type the formula in cell D5, you put -1 for col and it will give result of cell C5; you put -2 for col > cell B5. Same for Row, put -1 > D4; -2 > D3. Together? -1 -1 > C3; -3 +4 > A9.